# Wrap JSON data into an excel file using 'xlsxwriter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

[image]I am trying to wrap JSON data into an excel file by using xlsxwriter and data is not writing into the excel. I got this error when running the program.

```
Could not load source '<string>': Source unavailable.
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: You'll need to create a minimal reproducible example: in short, share your code.

Answer (score 1):

From your error, it appears that the path to the file provided to xlsxwriter is incorrect. In your case, it can be wrong path for JSON file you are reading or excel file you are writing to as you didn't mention where the error occurred.

**EDIT:**

This seems to be error with Visual Studio Code as depicted here https://github.com/Microsoft/ptvsd/issues/1389 . Please try calling the program from terminal directly.

Comment: No shirish,I have given excel path and tried with raw string like r"c:\folder\excel.xlsx" and it didn't work for me